# Warning message: 'newdata' had 1 row but variables found have 0 rows

Tags: r

```
library(ISLR)
lm.fit = lm(mpg[-1]~weight[-1], Auto)
predict(lm.fit, data.frame(weight = Auto$weight[1]))
```

Why does this code cause the following error:

```
Warning message:
'newdata' had 1 row but variables found have 0 rows
```

It doesn't cause an error for any other index but 1.

Comment: I get an error for every index I try. ... Edit: Oh, wait -- I think I get it, you mean when you change the '1' to another value in both lines, not just the predict line.

Comment: @Gleb_b just the lm.fit line actually, the index in the predict line doesn't matter.

Comment: I can't explain the behavior. I can get a prediction though.

Comment: e.g. via the rather silly `predict(lm.fit,new.data=data.frame(Auto))[1]`

Answer (score 2):

When you use

```
lm.fit = lm(mpg[-1]~weight[-1], Auto)
```

R creates a variable called `weight[-1]`. You can see this in the `lm.fit` object. The datafame of the predict function contain `weight` but not `weight[-1]`

Try

```
lm.fit = lm(mpg~weight, Auto[-1,])
```